# jQuery obtaining class information

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make something so a user can select an item from a list, I then add the class `selected` to the `div`, now I'd like to find this selected item again, how would I do this?

Ex.
`<div class="item"></div> <div class="item"></div <div class="item selected"></div>`

How can I make jquery return the class that has "selected" (and also has the class item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery objects can be accessed in the same way as CSS selectors. Try this.

```
$('.item.selected')
```

Comment: Sorry, I feel stupid, I honestly was so close, I just had to remove the space. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of a selected element by using `getAttr('class')`.

For example,

```
$('.selected').first().getAttr('class') // this will return 'item selected'
```

Notice the use of first() function, as the selector will return all of the elements that match the class. This will work if only one is selected. You may parse the result to find your 'item' class.